# Why $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor≤\frac{n}{p-1}$?

Tags: prime-numbers

I need some help: can someone tell me why

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor≤\frac{n}{p-1}$$

I found this inequality in Wikipedia, and I want to know if it's true, thanks!

Comment: We have $\lfloor x\rfloor \leqslant x$. Then you need to know how to sum a geometric series.

Comment: I guess that it is assumed that $p>1$.

Comment: I forgot to say $p$ prime, so yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor\leq \frac{n}{p^k} $$
and:
$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{p^k}=\frac{1}{p-1}.$$

Comment: for $p \gt 1$ $ $

Comment: yes, I forgot $p$ prime, thanks!